# Dose external storage exist on all devices running with API +11?

Tags: android, android-memory, android-external-storage

I am going to use android download manager. do I have to worry about existence of external storage? Are there any devices that do not have external storage?

**I think removable SD card and external storage are two different things. am I right?**

Comment: I think `removable SD card` and `external storage` are two different things. am I right?

Comment: @Funkystein - no, that is incorrect.  Most devices have an "external storage" (for the API meaning of external) - but it is not necessarily "external" or removable.  On most device today it is permanently installed (really just a meta-partition on the internal storage).  SD card slots are most often treated as *secondary* external storage today - but it depends on the device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> do I have to worry about existence of external storage?

Not usually. While, as Mr. Stratton points out in a comment to this quetion, there's nothing *stopping* a manufacturer from making external storage be some sort of removable card, that would be unusual on modern devices.

> Are there any devices that do not have external storage?

All devices that have a licensed copy of the Play Store ship with at least 1GB of external storage, as [that is required by the Compatibility Definition Document for Android 3.0+ releases](http://source.android.com/compatibility/downloads.html). Frequently, the device has more. Whether there is *space* on external storage for what you want is another matter.

> I think removable SD card and external storage are two different things. am I right?

Yes, [external storage](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html) and [removable storage](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html) are different things. They are also different than [internal storage](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html).

Comment: "All devices that have a licensed copy of the Play Store ship with at least 1GB of external storage" true, **but ultimately misleading** as in addition to possibly being full, one can't assume that the storage is currently installed in the device.  While it is *uncommon* today to implement the primary external storage as a removable card, I don't believe there is anything prohibiting a vendor from doing that.  All of the secondary storage rules would not apply to this if it were the *primary* rather than secondary storage.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: Hence, my "not usually" statement. I have not heard of this being an issue for mainstream devices in quite some time.

Comment: From your own link: "It is illustrative to consider two common examples. If a device implementation includes an SD card slot to satisfy the shared storage
requirement, a FAT-formatted SD card 1GB in size or larger MUST be included with the device as sold to users, and MUST be
mounted by default. Alternatively, if a device implementation uses internal fixed storage to satisfy this requirement..." In other words, a card which the user can remove is still a valid way to satisfy the external storage requirement.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: Hence, my "not usually" statement. If you can name any device with a licensed copy of the Play Store that behaves as you describe, please do so. I would love to add one to my device farm.